# How could I solve the openCV issues on python - library not loaded : @rpath/libglib-2.0.0.dylib

Tags: python, opencv, conda, jupyter-lab

I encountered this problem after installing opencv with : conda install -c conda-forge opencv

```
import cv2
```

Here is the error I get

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-155-864860d2a115> in <module>
----> 1 import cv2
      2

ImportError: dlopen(/Users/name/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libglib-2.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/name/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/libharfbuzz.0.dylib
  Reason: Incompatible library version: libharfbuzz.0.dylib requires version 5601.0.0 or later, but libglib-2.0.0.dylib provides version 0.0.0
```

$ conda list

```
absl-py                   0.11.0           py36h79c6626_0    conda-forge
appnope                   0.1.2            py36h79c6626_0    conda-forge
argon2-cffi               20.1.0           py36h6941dd6_2    conda-forge
asn1crypto                1.4.0              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
astor                     0.8.1              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
astunparse                1.6.3                    pypi_0    pypi
async_generator           1.10                       py_0    conda-forge
attrs                     20.3.0             pyhd3deb0d_0    conda-forge
backcall                  0.2.0              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
backports                 1.0                        py_2    conda-forge
backports.functools_lru_cache 1.6.1                      py_0    conda-forge
bitarray                  1.6.0                    pypi_0    pypi
bleach                    3.2.1              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
boost-cpp                 1.70.0               hd59e818_1    conda-forge
branca                    0.3.1                      py_0    conda-forge
brotlipy                  0.7.0           py36ha3de816_1001    conda-forge
bzip2                     1.0.8                hc929b4f_4    conda-forge
c-ares                    1.17.1               hc929b4f_0    conda-forge
ca-certificates           2020.12.5            h033912b_0    conda-forge
cachetools                4.2.1                    pypi_0    pypi
cairo                     1.16.0            h0ab9d94_1001    conda-forge
canmatrix                 0.8                        py_0    conda-forge
cchardet                  2.1.7            py36h27176af_0    conda-forge
certifi                   2020.12.5        py36h79c6626_1    conda-forge
cffi                      1.14.4           py36h1b827b8_0    conda-forge
chardet                   3.0.4           py36h2432673_1008    conda-forge
click                     7.1.2              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
click-plugins             1.1.1                      py_0    conda-forge
cligj                     0.7.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
cloudpickle               1.3.0                      py_0  
cmake                     3.12.2               haff7e42_0  
cryptography              2.3.1            py36hdbc3d79_0  
curl                      7.61.1               ha441bb4_0  
cycler                    0.10.0                     py_2    conda-forge
cytoolz                   0.11.0           py36h7b4949f_1    conda-forge
dask-core                 2020.12.0          pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
decorator                 4.4.2                      py_0    conda-forge
defusedxml                0.6.0                      py_0    conda-forge
descartes                 1.1.0                      py_4    conda-forge
entrypoints               0.3             pyhd8ed1ab_1003    conda-forge
enum34                    1.1.10           py36h9f0ad1d_2    conda-forge
expat                     2.2.9                hb1e8313_2    conda-forge
fastparquet               0.5.0            py36h809c706_0    conda-forge
ffmpeg                    4.0                  h01ea3c9_0  
fiona                     1.7.12           py36h0dff353_0  
flatbuffers               1.12                     pypi_0    pypi
folium                    0.10.1                     py_0    conda-forge
fontconfig                2.13.1            h1027ab8_1000    conda-forge
freetype                  2.10.4               h3f75d11_0    conda-forge
freexl                    1.0.5             h0b31af3_1002    conda-forge
future                    0.18.2           py36h79c6626_2    conda-forge
gast                      0.3.3                    pypi_0    pypi
gdal                      2.2.4            py36h6440ff4_1  
geographiclib             1.50                       py_0    conda-forge
geojson                   2.5.0                      py_0    conda-forge
geopandas                 0.6.1                      py_0  
geopy                     2.1.0              pyhd3deb0d_0    conda-forge
geos                      3.6.2             h0a44026_1004    conda-forge
gettext                   0.19.8.1          haf92f58_1004    conda-forge
giflib                    5.1.7                h01d97ff_1    conda-forge
glib                      2.58.3          py36hb0ce7ff_1004    conda-forge
google-auth               1.27.0                   pypi_0    pypi
google-auth-oauthlib      0.4.2                    pypi_0    pypi
google-pasta              0.2.0              pyh8c360ce_0    conda-forge
graphite2                 1.3.13            h2e338ed_1001    conda-forge
graphviz                  2.42.3               h98dfb87_0    conda-forge
grpcio                    1.32.0                   pypi_0    pypi
gym                       0.17.3           py36h9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
h5py                      2.10.0                   pypi_0    pypi
harfbuzz                  1.8.8                hb8d4a28_0  
haversine                 2.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
hdf4                      4.2.13            h71d84a9_1004    conda-forge
hdf5                      1.10.2               hc401514_3    conda-forge
icu                       58.2              h0a44026_1000    conda-forge
idna                      2.10               pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
imagecodecs-lite          2019.12.3        py36h8062767_3    conda-forge
imageio                   2.9.0                      py_0    conda-forge
imgkit                    1.0.2                    pypi_0    pypi
importlib-metadata        3.1.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
importlib_metadata        3.1.1                hd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
install                   1.3.4                    pypi_0    pypi
ipykernel                 5.1.4            py36h39e3cac_0    anaconda
ipyleaflet                0.13.3             pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
ipython                   7.12.0           py36h5ca1d4c_0    conda-forge
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                      py_1    conda-forge
ipywidgets                7.5.1                      py_0    conda-forge
jasper                    2.0.14               h45d9283_1    conda-forge
jedi                      0.17.2           py36h79c6626_1    conda-forge
jinja2                    2.11.2             pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
joblib                    0.17.0                     py_0    conda-forge
jpeg                      9d                   hbcb3906_0    conda-forge
json-c                    0.13.1            h575e443_1002    conda-forge
json5                     0.9.5              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
jsonschema                3.2.0                      py_2    conda-forge
jupyter_client            6.1.7                      py_0    conda-forge
jupyter_contrib_core      0.3.3                      py_2    conda-forge
jupyter_core              4.7.0            py36h79c6626_0    conda-forge
jupyter_latex_envs        1.4.6           py36h9f0ad1d_1001    conda-forge
jupyterlab                2.2.9                      py_0    conda-forge
jupyterlab_pygments       0.1.2              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
jupyterlab_server         1.2.0                      py_0    conda-forge
kealib                    1.4.7                h40e48e4_6  
keplergl                  0.2.2                    pypi_0    pypi
keras                     2.3.1                    py36_0    conda-forge
keras-applications        1.0.8                      py_1    conda-forge
keras-preprocessing       1.1.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
kiwisolver                1.3.1            py36he46ecad_0    conda-forge
lcms2                     2.11                 h11f7e16_1    conda-forge
libblas                   3.8.0               17_openblas    conda-forge
libcblas                  3.8.0               17_openblas    conda-forge
libcurl                   7.61.1               hf30b1f0_0  
libcxx                    11.0.0               h4c3b8ed_1    conda-forge
libdap4                   3.19.1               h3d3e54a_0  
libedit                   3.1.20191231         h0678c8f_2    conda-forge
libffi                    3.2.1             hb1e8313_1007    conda-forge
libgdal                   2.2.4                h7b1ea53_1  
libgfortran               3.0.1                         0    conda-forge
libiconv                  1.16                 haf1e3a3_0    conda-forge
libkml                    1.3.0             hed7d534_1010    conda-forge
liblapack                 3.8.0               17_openblas    conda-forge
libllvm10                 10.0.1               h009f743_3    conda-forge
libnetcdf                 4.6.1                h4e6abe9_2  
libopenblas               0.3.10               h0794777_0  
libopencv                 3.4.2                h7c891bd_1  
libopus                   1.3.1                hc929b4f_1    conda-forge
libpng                    1.6.37               h7cec526_2    conda-forge
libpq                     10.6              hbe1e24e_1000    conda-forge
libprotobuf               3.14.0               hfd3ada9_0    conda-forge
libsodium                 1.0.18               hbcb3906_1    conda-forge
libspatialindex           1.9.3                h4a8c4bd_3    conda-forge
libspatialite             4.3.0a              ha12ebda_19  
libssh2                   1.8.0                h322a93b_4  
libtiff                   4.1.0                hca7d577_6    conda-forge
libuuid                   1.0.3                h6bb4b03_2  
libvpx                    1.7.0                h378b8a2_0  
libwebp-base              1.1.0                hbcb3906_3    conda-forge
libxml2                   2.9.10               h7cdb67c_3  
libxslt                   1.1.34               h83b36ba_0  
llvm-openmp               11.0.0               h73239a0_1    conda-forge
llvmlite                  0.35.0           py36hf7e63e9_1    conda-forge
lxml                      4.6.2            py36h34aa933_0    conda-forge
lz4                       3.1.1            py36hcce9a2f_0    conda-forge
lz4-c                     1.9.2                hb1e8313_3    conda-forge
markdown                  3.3.3              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
markupsafe                1.1.1            py36ha3de816_2    conda-forge
matplotlib                3.3.3            py36h79c6626_0    conda-forge
matplotlib-base           3.3.3            py36h50af36e_0    conda-forge
mdfreader                 4.1                      pypi_0    pypi
mistune                   0.8.4           py36h6941dd6_1002    conda-forge
mpmath                    1.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
msgpack                   0.5.6                    pypi_0    pypi
munch                     2.5.0                      py_0    conda-forge
natsort                   7.1.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
nbclient                  0.5.1                      py_0    conda-forge
nbconvert                 6.0.7            py36h79c6626_3    conda-forge
nbformat                  5.0.8                      py_0    conda-forge
ncurses                   6.2                  h2e338ed_4    conda-forge
nest-asyncio              1.4.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
networkx                  2.5                        py_0    conda-forge
nodejs                    10.13.0              h0a44026_0  
notebook                  6.1.4                    py36_0  
numba                     0.52.0           py36h2be6da3_0    conda-forge
numexpr                   2.7.1            py36h72eec15_3    conda-forge
numpy                     1.19.4           py36h08dc641_2    conda-forge
oauthlib                  3.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
olefile                   0.46               pyh9f0ad1d_1    conda-forge
opencv                    3.4.2            py36h6fd60c2_1    anaconda
openjpeg                  2.3.1                h6cbf5cd_3    conda-forge
openssl                   1.0.2u               h0b31af3_0    conda-forge
opt-einsum                3.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
overpy                    0.4                        py_0    conda-forge
packaging                 20.7               pyhd3deb0d_0    conda-forge
pandas                    1.1.5            py36h2be6da3_0    conda-forge
pandoc                    2.11.2               hc929b4f_0    conda-forge
pandocfilters             1.4.2                      py_1    conda-forge
parso                     0.7.0                      py_0  
pathlib                   1.0.1                    py36_1  
pcre                      8.44                 hb1e8313_0    conda-forge
pdfkit                    0.6.1                    pypi_0    pypi
pexpect                   4.8.0              pyh9f0ad1d_2    conda-forge
pickleshare               0.7.5                   py_1003    conda-forge
pillow                    8.0.0            py36h1a82f1a_0    anaconda
pip                       20.3.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pixman                    0.38.0            h01d97ff_1003    conda-forge
poppler                   0.67.0               hb974355_6    conda-forge
poppler-data              0.4.10                        0    conda-forge
proj4                     5.0.1                h1de35cc_0  
prometheus_client         0.9.0              pyhd3deb0d_0    conda-forge
prompt-toolkit            3.0.8              pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
prompt_toolkit            3.0.8                hd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
protobuf                  3.14.0           py36h22858aa_0    conda-forge
psutil                    5.7.3                    pypi_0    pypi
ptyprocess                0.6.0                   py_1001    conda-forge
py-opencv                 3.4.2            py36h7c891bd_1  
py4j                      0.10.9                   pypi_0    pypi
pyarrow                   3.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pyasn1                    0.4.8                    pypi_0    pypi
pyasn1-modules            0.2.8                    pypi_0    pypi
pycparser                 2.20               pyh9f0ad1d_2    conda-forge
pydot                     1.4.1                    pypi_0    pypi
pyglet                    1.5.0            py36h9f0ad1d_1    conda-forge
pygments                  2.7.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyopenssl                 19.0.0                   py36_0  
pyparsing                 2.4.7              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
pyproj                    3.0.0.post1              pypi_0    pypi
pyrsistent                0.17.3           py36h6941dd6_1    conda-forge
pysocks                   1.7.1            py36h2432673_2    conda-forge
pyspark                   3.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
python                    3.6.6                hc167b69_0  
python-dateutil           2.8.1                      py_0    conda-forge
python-snappy             0.5.4            py36h8d68209_3    conda-forge
python_abi                3.6                     1_cp36m    conda-forge
pytz                      2020.4             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pywavelets                1.1.1            py36h809c706_3    conda-forge
pyyaml                    5.3.1            py36ha3de816_1    conda-forge
pyzmq                     20.0.0           py36h8302150_1    conda-forge
readline                  7.0               hcfe32e1_1001    conda-forge
requests                  2.25.0             pyhd3deb0d_0    conda-forge
requests-oauthlib         1.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
rhash                     1.3.6             haf1e3a3_1001    conda-forge
rsa                       4.7.1                    pypi_0    pypi
rtree                     0.9.4            py36h49c2f37_2    conda-forge
scikit-image              0.17.2           py36h81aa140_0    anaconda
scikit-learn              0.23.2           py36h751d9b8_3    conda-forge
scipy                     1.2.1            py36hbd7caa9_1    conda-forge
seaborn                   0.11.0                     py_0    anaconda
selenium                  3.141.0         py36h9de38fb_1002    conda-forge
send2trash                1.5.0                      py_0    conda-forge
setuptools                49.6.0           py36h2432673_2    conda-forge
shapely                   1.7.1                    pypi_0    pypi
six                       1.15.0             pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
snappy                    1.1.8                hb1e8313_3    conda-forge
sqlite                    3.33.0               hffcf06c_0  
sympy                     1.6.2                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorboard               2.4.1                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorboard-plugin-wit    1.8.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow                2.4.1                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-base           1.14.0           py36h9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
tensorflow-estimator      2.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
termcolor                 1.1.0                      py_2    conda-forge
terminado                 0.9.1            py36h79c6626_1    conda-forge
testpath                  0.4.4                      py_0    conda-forge
theano                    0.8.2                    py36_0    conda-forge
threadpoolctl             2.1.0              pyh5ca1d4c_0    conda-forge
thrift                    0.11.0          py36h4a8c4bd_1001    conda-forge
tifffile                  2019.7.26.2              py36_0    conda-forge
tk                        8.6.10               hb0a8c7a_1    conda-forge
toolz                     0.11.1                     py_0    conda-forge
tornado                   6.1              py36h6941dd6_0    conda-forge
traitlets                 4.3.3            py36h9f0ad1d_1    conda-forge
traittypes                0.2.1              pyh9f0ad1d_2    conda-forge
turfpy                    0.0.5              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
typing-extensions         3.7.4.3                  pypi_0    pypi
urllib3                   1.25.11                    py_0    conda-forge
utm                       0.7.0                    pypi_0    pypi
vincent                   0.4.4                      py_1    conda-forge
wcwidth                   0.2.5              pyh9f0ad1d_2    conda-forge
webencodings              0.5.1                      py_1    conda-forge
werkzeug                  1.0.1              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
wheel                     0.36.1             pyhd3deb0d_0    conda-forge
widgetsnbextension        3.5.1            py36h79c6626_4    conda-forge
wrapt                     1.12.1           py36h7b4949f_2    conda-forge
xerces-c                  3.2.2             h4db8090_1003    conda-forge
xlrd                      1.2.0              pyh9f0ad1d_1    conda-forge
xlsxwriter                1.3.7              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
xlwt                      1.3.0                      py_1    conda-forge
xz                        5.2.5                haf1e3a3_1    conda-forge
yaml                      0.2.5                haf1e3a3_0    conda-forge
zeromq                    4.3.3                h74dc148_3    conda-forge
zipp                      3.4.0                      py_0    conda-forge
zlib                      1.2.11            h7795811_1010    conda-forge
zstd                      1.4.5                h289c70a_2    conda-forge
```

$ conda info

```
     active environment : myenv
    active env location : /Users/name/anaconda3/envs/myenv
            shell level : 2
       user config file : /Users/name/.condarc
 populated config files : /Users/name/.condarc
          conda version : 4.9.2
    conda-build version : 3.18.11
         python version : 3.7.6.final.0
       virtual packages : __osx=10.15.4=0
                          __unix=0=0
                          __archspec=1=x86_64
       base environment : /Users/name/anaconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : /Users/name/anaconda3/pkgs
                          /Users/name/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /Users/name/anaconda3/envs
                          /Users/name/.conda/envs
               platform : osx-64
             user-agent : conda/4.9.2 requests/2.25.0 CPython/3.7.6 Darwin/19.4.0 OSX/10.15.4
                UID:GID : 501:20
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

Answer (score 0):

I just created a new environment and everything works well.